# Can typescript's constant folding parse constant arrays?

Tags: typescript

What I want is to compile these long codes into short few lines and collapse all constants:

```js
type BodyPart = "move" | "work" | "carry";

const CostMap: Record<BodyPart, number> = {
    move: 50,
    work: 100,
    carry: 50,
};

class MyBody {
    readonly cost: number;
    constructor(public readonly body: BodyPart[]) {
        this.cost = body.reduce((sum, body_part) => sum + CostMap[body_part], 0);
    }
}

const BodyMap: Record<string, MyBody> = {
    worker: new MyBody(["work", "carry", "move", "move"]),
    carrier: new MyBody(["carry", "move"]),
};

export { BodyMap };
```

Expected javascript result:

```js
const BodyMap = {
    worker: { body: ["work", "carry", "move", "move"], cost: 250 },
    carrier: { body: ["carry", "move"], cost: 100 },
};

export { BodyMap };
```

Is this a tough task for typescript? Or should I use other specialized optimization tools for more complex constant folding. But as you can see, these constants depend on some type definitions, and I suspect other tools might not understand my intent correctly.

I know that typescript supports rest parameters in generics, like `SomeType<T extends any[]>`, but how do I convert these types to variable values?

Comment: TypeScript won't inline a constructor call, and certainly won't inline a `reduce`. :-)

Comment: What a sad news, is there any hacky way to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Jin I'm by no means an expert on the subject, but if you don't mind using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) then you could write your own [transform plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins/#transform-plugins) that statically analyses your code and pre-computes any `new MyBody` calls at compile time.

Comment: Why not just a function that constructs the right object?

Comment: The constructor call can indeed be replaced with a function that returns the correct object. But for `reduce` operations on constant arrays, I didn't find information on how to fold them. I went through some information about typescript type metaprogramming and it's a really complicated process to do it this way. The same is true for the babel plugin. Honestly, folding of these constants doesn't bring much performance gain either. So in the end I chose to give up.

Comment: Pardon me, but since when does TypeScript do constant folding?